# cannot subscribe FB page to FB app recently

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a FB app that works well before. It allows users to subscribe their pages to our app.
Recently, I got the error below when trying to subscribe a page to our app:

'Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active apps or apps that have not recently accessed this data due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform.'

I am using this request url: https://graph.facebook.com/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=xxx
It worked great before but not for now.
However, when I try to submit the same request with the 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
it works.

Anyone canshow me how can I fix this problem?
Thanks,
Thanh

Comment: There should be no difference between making this request from your code, or GAE. Likely you used the GAE app id in the latter case, so that you did not actually test your app to begin with. // There really isn’t much you can do about this right now, expect wait until Facebook figures their stuff out. https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/

Answer (score 1):

Have the same issue here. My APP uses Facebook Graph API to import events. Credentials for APP (token) was enabled a long time ago....

Now seems its throwing and error also at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/1405126029586258?method=GET&path=157956504840454%2Fevents&version=v2.12

Nether my APP or Graph API is working. Below the error message....

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '157956504840454' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "EHCB6/XyJsA"
  }
}
```

[Same error on my app at Wordpress to import events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74vBe.png)

Message from Facebook answering the question...

As we begin enhancing our new app review process and make changes to our platform, the Events, Groups, Pages and Instagram APIs will no longer be available to new developers. Testing of our more robust process starts today and the new process should resume in a few weeks, but apps currently accessing Events and Groups APIs will lose access today. Going forward, access to these APIs will require a formal app review and for apps using the Pages API, submission is required within 90 days once app review resumes or access will be removed.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for your post. Is there anything we can do to fix it?

Comment: Take a look at this link https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/04/restricting-data-access/  also looking for how to fix it. As i understood we need to wait a few weeks cause api os freezed.